# Count the length of an array with bigquery returns 1 when empty

Tags: google-bigquery

I have text string like the following:

```
text_string    
"1","4","9","8","12","10","7","13","15","5","14"
```

And I need to count the number of members. So, for this I'm using the following function:

```
ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(text_string,","))    which returns 11 and it is fine.
```

But when `text_string` is empty, it always returns 1.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SPLIT` [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split) says,

> Splitting an empty STRING returns an ARRAY with a single empty STRING.

I'm not totally sure but couldn't you do something like,

```
IF(text_string = "", 0, ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(text_string,",")))
```